How to get desired Boundary Edges?
There is a node called Edge Neighbors that can be used to select boundary edges (AKA non-manifold edges).
In this case there is geometry with 3 hole
The question is how to get only a single linked boundary edges?,
For example, I want to select the boundary edges in the middle hole
and then transform it (not separating).
What node should I use to get desired boundary edges?
Thank you.
 
*the viewport in wireframe display mode

Do you need this to be a reusable node tree that will work on many different meshes or only for this scenario?

I need it for reusable node.

How do you know which "border" to select out of 3 ? Is it because it is the "middle" one ? In other words, what is the selection mask for this particular border ?

@StefLAncien The middle border is just an example, the goal is only to select (any) one border.
i mean, it's possible if you separate that 3 border then use Mesh Island node + Compare node, then you can switch between border using integer.
so i think there's a way to select the specific border without separating.

(Using Blender 4.2.0)
The proposed approach is based on a Separate Geometry>Join Geometry>Merge by Distance nodes sequence taking advantage of the merge averaging process to compute a "border" index per boundary, while keeping a single mesh, without islands.

Green frame:
1. The "border" index is initialized at -1 and stored as a Named Attribute in Edge domain.
2. Edges belonging to a single face are separated from the main geometry. They are grouped as Mesh Islands, one per boundary.
3. For those edges, the "border" index is computed as $2I+1$ with $I$ the Island Index.
4. Then the separated edges are joined back with the main geometry. After this step, boundary edges are duplicated, the original ones with a "border" attribute set to -1, the separated ones with a "border" attribute set to $2I+1$.
5. Eventually, duplicated elements are removed using a Merge by Distance node. Original vertices and edges are preserved, but "border" attributes are averaged as $\frac{1}{2} ( -1 + (2I+1) )=I$.
Blue frame:
To illustrate how such a "border" index can be used, firstly a Mesh to Points node set in Edge domain is connected with a selection mask keeping only edges with a "border" attribute higher than -1, the default value for all original edges. Then this same attribute is used by an Instance on Points node to pick different meshes to spawn, one per boundary.
Spreadsheet Editor:
A Row Filter on the "border" attribute shows that 96 edges out of 2736 are belonging to a boundary, whose index ranges from 0 to 2.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.0+)
